# Unhandled exception at 0x74A635D2 in Project2.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x012FDBC4

Tags: c++, pointers

I've created this class called "Consulta Bool" which is supposed to create a tree-like stucture. I use this class to make a Boolean Consult. That's why I've created a the class (I'm obligated to use a header file and a .cc file), here is the code for the header file and the .cc file:

````
struct token {
    string tipo; 
    string etq; 
    Date fini, ffin; 
};
//(there is an endif here)  

class ConsultaBool {
public:
    ConsultaBool(const string& s);
    ConsultaBool();
    ConsultaBool(const Date& fini, const Date& ffin); 
    ConsultaBool AND(ConsultaBool q2); 
    ConsultaBool OR(ConsultaBool q2);  
    ConsultaBool NOT();                       
    void read(istream& is);
    ConsultaBool getEsquerra();
    ConsultaBool getDreta();
    token getToken();

private: 
    token arrel;
    ConsultaBool* dreta; //dreta mins right side of the Bin Tree
    ConsultaBool* esquerra; //esquerra means left side 
};

(there is another endif here)'''```

and here comes the heavy stuff;


string toUpper(const string& s) {
    string res = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i)
        res += toupper(s[i]);
    return res;
}

void read_input(istream& is, vector<token>& l);
int precedence(string oper);
void convert_infix_to_postfix(const vector<token>& infix, vector<token>& postfix);
ConsultaBool construct_bool_query(const vector<token>& postfix);

ConsultaBool::ConsultaBool(const string& s) {
    this -> arrel.etq = s;
    this -> arrel.tipo = "TAG";
}

ConsultaBool::ConsultaBool(const Fecha& fini, const Fecha& ffin) {
    this ->arrel.fini = fini;
    this ->arrel.ffin = fini;
    this ->arrel.tipo = "DATE";
} 

ConsultaBool::ConsultaBool() {
    this->arrel.tipo = "#";
} 

token ConsultaBool::getToken() {
    return arrel;
}

ConsultaBool ConsultaBool::getDreta() {
    return *dreta;
}

ConsultaBool ConsultaBool::getEsquerra() {
    return *esquerra;
}
ConsultaBool ConsultaBool::AND(ConsultaBool q2) {
    ConsultaBool consulta;
    consulta.arrel.tipo = "AND";
    consulta.dreta = this;
    consulta.esquerra = &q2;
    return consulta;
} 

ConsultaBool ConsultaBool::OR(ConsultaBool q2) {
    ConsultaBool consulta;
    consulta.arrel.tipo = "OR";
    consulta.dreta = this;
    consulta.esquerra = &q2;
    return consulta;
}  

ConsultaBool ConsultaBool::NOT() {
    ConsultaBool consulta;
    consulta.arrel.tipo = "NOT";
    consulta.esquerra = this;
    return consulta;
}                       

ConsultaBool construct_bool_query(const vector<token>& postfix) {
    stack<ConsultaBool> S;
    for (int i = 0; i < postfix.size(); ++i) {
        token tk = postfix[i];
        if (tk.tipo == "TAG") S.push(ConsultaBool(tk.etq)); 
        if (tk.tipo == "DATE") S.push(ConsultaBool(tk.fini, tk.ffin)); 
        if (tk.tipo == "AND" or tk.tipo == "OR") {
            ConsultaBool q2 = S.top(); S.pop();
            ConsultaBool q1 = S.top(); S.pop();
            if (tk.tipo == "AND") S.push(q1.AND(q2)); 
            if (tk.tipo == "OR") S.push(q1.OR(q2)); 
        }
        if (tk.tipo == "NOT") {
            ConsultaBool q = S.top(); S.pop(); 
            S.push(q.NOT()); // apila una consulta 'not q'
        }
    }
    return S.top();
}

ConsultaBool::read(istream& is) {

    vector<token> infix, postfix;
    read_input(is, infix);
    if (infix.empty()) { 
        *this = ConsultaBool(); 
        return; 
    }
    convert_infix_to_postfix(infix, postfix);
    *this = construct_bool_query(postfix);
}

void read_input(istream& is, vector<token>& l) {
    string s; 
    is >> s; 
    while (s != "END_QUERY") {
        token tk;
        s = toUpper(s);
        tk.tipo = s;
        if (s == "(" or s == ")" or s == "AND" or s == "OR" or s == "NOT") { 
            l.push_back(tk);
        }
        if (s == "DATE") { /** usad el metodo Fecha::llegir() o similar si no teneis
                            sobrecargado el operador >> para leer fechas **/
            tk.fini.lee_fecha();
            tk.ffin.lee_fecha();
            l.push_back(tk);
        }
        if (s == "TAG") {
            is >> tk.etq;
            l.push_back(tk);
        }      
        is >> s;
    }
}

/**THEORETICALLY FROM THIS POINT ON EVERYTHING SHOULD BE CORRECT **/

int precedence(string oper) {
    if (oper == "OR") return 1;
    if (oper == "AND") return 2;
    if (oper == "NOT") return 3;
    return 0;
}

void convert_infix_to_postfix(const vector<token>& infix, vector<token>& postfix) {
    stack<token> S;
    token spc; spc.tipo = "#"; S.push(spc);
    for (int i = 0; i < infix.size(); ++i) {
        token tk = infix[i];
        if (tk.tipo == "DATE" or tk.tipo == "TAG")
            postfix.push_back(tk);
        else if (tk.tipo == "(" or tk.tipo == "NOT") 
            S.push(tk);
        else if (tk.tipo == ")") {
            while (S.top().tipo != "#" and S.top().tipo != "(") {
                postfix.push_back(S.top()); S.pop();
            }
            S.pop();
        } else {
            while (S.top().tipo != "#" and 
                precedence(tk.tipo) <= precedence(S.top().tipo)) {
                    postfix.push_back(S.top()); S.pop();
            }
            S.push(tk);
        }
    }
    while (S.top().tipo != "#") {
        postfix.push_back(S.top()); S.pop();
    } 
}
````

Sorry for just pasting the code. I have a problem when accessing the function "getEsquerra()" which is just a getter. It tells me Unhandled exception at 0x74A635D2 in Project2.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x012FDBC4.. Any idea why it might be happening?

Comment: Both uses of `consulta.esquerra = &q2;` take the address of a local variable which stops existing after the function ends. Even if you used `ConsultaBool & q2` it would just change the problem, since `OR` and `AND` look like they are only called on local variables anyway.

Comment: The basic problem is that you failed to use any dynamic allocation to create your tree, instead you used addresses of local variables to serve as pointers in the tree.  Unless I missed something, nowhere do you use `new`, `delete`, smart pointers, etc.